# Tensorflow.lite model produces wrong (different) results in Android app?

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I've made an Image classification model and converted it to tflite format.
Then I've verified tflite model in Python using tf.lite.Interpreter — it produces same results for my test image as the original model. Here's a [colab link to verify](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UPzavvgT8gFJFmRq5YfLJQxOIMuTrHtO#scrollTo=-Cek7B16sPUd).

Then I embedded it to a sample Android app, using [Android Studio ML Model Binding](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android?hl=en) and exact example code from Android studio.
Here's the [main activity code](https://github.com/EviGL/tensorflow_lite_issue_example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/isaac_android_test/MainActivity.kt), you can also use this link to navigate to the full android project.

```
val assetManager = this.assets
val istr = assetManager.open("test_image.JPG") //The same image
val b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr)

val model = Model2.newInstance(this) //Model definition generated by Android Studio

// Creates inputs for reference.
val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(b)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(image)
val probability = outputs.probabilityAsCategoryList
probability.sortByDescending { it.score }
val top9 = probability.take(9)

this.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.results_text).text = top9.toString()
```

And then I'm getting completely different results on Android for the same model and the same input image.

Here are results matching my initial model in Python:
[image: correct results in Python]

Here are wrong results I'm getting in Android app:

[image: wrong results on Android]

Links to the model and the test image are there in both examples, but I'll post them into the question once again:

[tflite model](https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/kJywrV6Xvg0f-Q)

[test image](https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/i/ky0ogY6shK2L8w)

I guess it has something to do with input/output formats of the model. Or the image is interpreted differently in python and in android. Or the [metadata I added to the model](https://pastebin.com/EheCqXVn) is somehow wrong. Anyways, I've tried everything to localize the issue and now I'm stuck.

How do I fix my model or Android code so it produces the same results as my python code?

Comment: Does the input image size match between your python/colab environment and your Android setup? If you just feed a JPG without resizing that could be a problem.

Comment: @MorrisonChang the image is resized to 32x32px with Nearest Neighbor algorithm for both cases, I checked in the debugger for Android code.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried again with 32x32px PNG as input for both cases to avoid any resizing, still same results.

Comment: Did you print the bit array and check if it is the same on python?
Besides, I would recommend to use ImageClassifier class follow: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/EXPLORE_THE_CODE.md#using-the-tensorflow-lite-task-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find and fix the issue:
My model from [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) included a built-in image normalization layer. Image normalization is when you transform standard **0-255** image color values to **0.0-1.0** float values, suitable for machine learning.

But the metadata I used for the tflite model included 2 parameters for external normalization: mean and std.
Formula for each value being: **normalized_value = (value - mean) / std**
Since my model handles its own normalization, I need to turn off external normalization by setting **mean = 0** and **std = 1**.
This way I'll get **normalized_value = value**.

So, setting the tflite metadata parameters to these:

```
    image_min=0,
    image_max=255.0,
    mean=[0.0],
    std=[1.0]
```

fixed the double normalization issue and my model now produces [correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgZI.jpg) in Android app.